# UML diagram showing interaction between angular components, services and shared services

Tags: angular, uml, component-diagram

I want to know what type of UML diagram can be used to show how components are interacting in Angular application.

Suppose i have Component A, and Component B. These both components talk through a Shared Service C, which means that Component A and Component B has dependency on Shared Service C.

I want to document this dependency using UML diagram.

Comment: How about a Component Diagram? I feel like I'm missing a crucial part of your question.

Comment: Have you read others questions on such subject ? Could you at least propose a schema ? And take care to the notion of components, this is often a confusing word.

Comment: @granier I am talking about pure angular components.

Comment: I am not familiar with Angular, but UML defines what is a component, so you should check if Angular definition fills the one of UML. You will find the UML definition looking to others questions about component.

Answer (score 2):

This shows that a component uses another one. Does this answer to your question ?

[image]

Comment: What is above diagram called and how do i show dependency of component with service?

Comment: UML speaking, what is a service or an Angular component ? As long as you do not provide this information we can not provide a better answer.

Comment: Angular Service and component both are just type script classes with properties and functions.

Comment: So you have two classes which interact ? How do they interact ?

Comment: Components uses services to make http calls, these services are injected into component constructor using angular DI framework.

Comment: Here you explain the dynamic part, but first you have to say what are services and components. Are they classes ?

Comment: Yes they are plain classes just like c# or java class

Comment: So, guy, why do not you propose your own schema ? Then we will correct it. Modeling two classes or a set of classes whith dependencies should not be to complex no ?

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, I would primarily recommend *sequence diagrams*. Each lifeline in the diagram represents an Angular component or service.

Based on my experience in designing Angular apps, I have written a white paper on the subject: [Technical design in UML for Angular applications](http://admiraalit.nl/admiraal/Technical-design-for-Angular-apps.pdf).